# What is the correct way to calculate an average frame rate?

Tags: r, frame-rate

The example is in R, but really it is a mathematics question.

I have a video. I have the times of a few successive frames (`tms`). They are in number of seconds after the video started.

```
tms <- c(0.06, 0.07, 0.26, 0.30, 0.33, 0.38, 0.47)
```

I want to calculate the average frame rate of the video.

I can think of two ways, and I cannot decide which one makes more sense. They do not give the same result, so surely one is inaccurate!

**Method 1**

```
mean(1/diff(tms))
```

> 32.45127

**Method 2**

```
1/mean(diff(tms))
```

> 14.63415

Which one is correct and why is the other one not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 2 is correct. Framerate is typically expressed as FPS, that is:

Total number of frames / total number of seconds

We can see the equivalence with this:

```r
tms <- c(0.06, 0.07, 0.26, 0.30, 0.33, 0.38, 0.47)

# total number of seconds
n_seconds <- sum(diff(tms))

# total number of frames
n_frames <- length(tms) - 1

# fps
n_frames / n_seconds
[1] 14.63415
```

Note that in the code above I set `n_frames` as `length(tms)-1` because the `diff` function always produces a vector with one less entry than the original vector (it is a *differencing* tool). You could add 0 to your `tms` vector at the start.